# Service timeout while accessing from IIS 7.5

Tags: wcf, exception, timeout, iis-7.5, nettcpbinding

Configuration: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, IIS 7.5

Web site is accessing service deployed on different server (which is Windows Server 2003)

I can access service from my local machine; I have web site hosted in IIS 7.5 on my  machine which is Win 7 Box. This works just fine.

Error:

```
[SocketException (0x2746): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host]
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing) +276

[CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:10:00'.]
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing) +16433296
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout) +132
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +66
   System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +60
   System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +64
   System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +54
   System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +379

[IOException: The read operation failed, see inner exception.]
   System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +659
   System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +170
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout) +187

[CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:10:00'.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +4727747
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +1725
   AB.RAPPublisher.InterfaceExt.IRAPPublisher.GetDashboardMessages(String messageType, DateTime businessDate) +0
   AB.RAPPublisher.Client.RAPPublisherClient.GetDashboardMessages(String messageType, DateTime businessDate) +235
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you Non-HTTP Activation installed, Net.Tcp Listener and Windows Process Activation services running?

Comment: My service is not installed within IIS..only web site is accessed. Service is installed on seperate machine... and it throws this above error while that service through web site

Comment: @Ocean: Have you installed and turned on this features on the server where your web service is running?

Comment: it is not web service it is wcf service. And Wcf service is not  hosted in IIS. It is hosted as stand alone service in different machine.

Comment: @Ocean: WCF service *is* a web service. WCF is a web service framework. Just FYI. Ok. So you have self-hosting WCF service. It still requires the windows services I've listed.

Comment: I am able to figure out problem; it was Authentication issue. All the services you mentioned were already installed...Sorry for confusion; when you say web service i was still thinking as old .aspx web services. Thanks for your help and pointers...

Comment: @Ocean: Glad the issue is solved. May I suggest to post the way you solved it as an answer and accept it?